# powershell forEach loop cycling through more times than needed and starting with the wrong file

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I am running a forEach loop in powershell to copy some SQL files to a specific folder, but I am getting some very strange output and the order of the files being copied is not making sense, hoping someone can see what I am doing wrong.

I have my files in order in a csv like such:

```
HelloWorld1.sql
HelloWorld2.sql
HelloWorld3.sql
HelloWorld4.sql
```

here is the loop:

```
ForEach ($column in $newfile){
    
    if($column.Extension -eq 'sql'){

        $path = $column.folder 

        $File = $column.Filename

        $path += '\'

        $updatedPath = "C:\PathToOriginalLocation\$path$File"
    
     }

    Write-Host "copying" "$newPath\$path$File"

    echo f | xcopy /f /s /e /q /y $updatedPath "$newPath\$path"
```

the output I am getting looks like this

```
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld4.sql"
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld4.sql"
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld1.sql" 
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld2.sql"  
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld2.sql"
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld3.sql"
copying "C:\PathToNewLocation\HelloWorld4.sql"
```

can someone help me through why it is starting with number 4 twice, then going to number 1, then does number 2 twice, does number 3, and then does number 4 again?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tdHf.png)

Thanks All!

Comment: 2 questions on my end. What is the point of piping to `xcopy`? Why not use `Copy-Item`?

Comment: Given your example of your CSV your code does not work. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32349307) your question to provide better examples to go with your code.

Comment: Abraham Zinala, I could use copy-item, I just chose not to

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I have added a snippet of the csv, does that help?

Comment: It does, and it explains why you're seeing what you are. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are running the loop in a polluted session. If you close PowerShell and run it fresh you would see different results, but since you've run the loop, and are running it again it is following your logic as you defined it.

It loops through your CSV entries, starting with the `FileName = Tables` line.

It runs the `If` statement first:

```
if($column.Extension -eq 'sql'){

    $path = $column.folder 

    $File = $column.Filename

    $path += '\'

    $updatedPath = "C:\PathToOriginalLocation\$path$File"

 }
```

But `$column.Extension` does not equal `'sql'`, so it skips that scriptblock and moves on to run the next line:

```
Write-Host "copying" "$newPath\$path$File"
```

So, since it skipped the `If` scriptblock it did not define `$file`, `$path`, or `$updatedPath`, and it uses the last thing those were set to, which was from when the script was previously run, and the last thing that assigned them the previous run was the `HelloWorld4.sql` record. That is why those are showing up at the top when you run this. The exact same thing is happening on the `ViewsFuncSP` record, and it is repeating the variables that were set on the record before it. Clear your variables in each loop and that won't happen, but I think a better solution is to include all of your lines that you want run for a `.sql` file to be within the `If` scriptblock. Something like this:

```
ForEach ($column in $newfile){
    
    if($column.Extension -eq 'sql'){

        $path = $column.folder 

        $File = $column.Filename

        $path += '\'

        $updatedPath = "C:\PathToOriginalLocation\$path$File"

        Write-Host "copying" "$newPath\$path$File"

        echo f | xcopy /f /s /e /q /y $updatedPath "$newPath\$path"
    }
```

Now, why it is showing `HelloWorld4.sql` twice, that doesn't make sense from your screenshot. I'm guessing it is related to how you are reading your CSV file, and somehow including the header row as a record. You don't show that line so it's hard to say and I can only speculate.

Comment: It only makes sense to me while that pipe is there, it'll display twice. Seems unnecessary to begin with unless i'm misunderstanding why it's there.